# add a variable when setting a javascript cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've been trying to add a variable when setting a cookie but no luck. The cookie is created but the value is not passed and it appears as +content+

```
 function createCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain) {
  var cookie = name + "=" + value + ";";

  if (expires) {
    // If it's a date
    if(expires instanceof Date) {
      // If it isn't a valid date
      if (isNaN(expires.getTime()))
       expires = new Date();
    }
    else
      expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(expires) * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

    cookie += "expires=" + expires.toGMTString() + ";";
  }

  if (path)
    cookie += "path=" + path + ";";
  if (domain)
    cookie += "domain=" + domain + ";";

  document.cookie = cookie;
    }

      function updateCookie(){
var content = "value of cookie";
         createCookie("newcookie", "+content+", new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10000));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
var content = "value of cookie";
createCookie("newcookie", content , new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10000));
```

Comment: thanks so much, I swear I tried that before I asked.